# Why does my Ajax Get request give a 400 bad request?

Tags: ajax

I'm quite new to Wordpress and I am trying to do an ajax request inside a code snippet from the code snippet plugin. The problem is that I keep getting a status 400 bad request. I found many people with the same problem but none of them were using code snippets. So I think it's a little different so I'm not really sure what to do. This is my code.

From what I can see from the network tab the request appears to be going to the correct URL.

[sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=test](http://sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=test)

I tried to log the error but all it gives me is an object. I looked in the object with var_dump and from what I can see it had the same error and not much more.

```
function do_ajax_get()
{
    echo "request succesfull";
    die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_test', 'do_ajax_get');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'do_ajax_get');

function do_make_button()
{
    return '<button type="button" onclick="fetch_data()">
        Click Me!
    </button>
    <script>
        function fetch_data()
        {
            var data = {
                "action":"test"
            };

            $.ajax({
              url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
              data: data,
              type: "GET",
              success: function(data){ 
                  console.log("succes");
              },
              error: function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
              }
            });
        }
    </script>';
}
add_shortcode('ajax_test', 'do_make_button');
```

Comment: look what append with the Network Monitor of your browser. If you use Firefox, you can show it with Ctrl + Shift + E
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: Anything I'm looking for specifically?  It appears to be making the request to the correct URL: http://sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=test

Comment: That `function fetch()` overrides the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (`window.fetch`), so don't do that or that you should use unique function names. And in what file did you put your PHP code? Because it seems fine, so it's possible that your callbacks are registered *late* - i.e. after WordPress runs the `wp_ajax_` hooks. You can confirm that by visiting `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=test` - is it showing a `0`?

Comment: It wasn't the function name, I edited the question with a better function name. Yes, it is indeed showing 0. Is there anyway I can register it before from within the same snippet?

Comment: Yes, I was just saying use a function name that's not a reserved JS word. And "register within the same snippet" - yes, maybe you can, if the file is loaded before WordPress runs the `wp_ajax_` hooks. But usually, one would put AJAX callbacks in the theme `functions.php` file or a file loaded in the root of the functions file.

Answer (score 0):

Your nopriv action has wrong syntax.
`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'do_ajax_get');`

Comment: I edited the question. I sadly did not solve the problem.